# __str__ returned non-string (type takimlar)

Tags: django

hi i couldn't solve this problem. I would appreciate if you help.

```
class Musabaka(models.Model):
kuno=models.ForeignKey(Club,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Kulüp")
seno=models.ForeignKey(Sezon,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Sezon")
rano=models.ForeignKey(takimlar,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Rakip Takım")
katno=models.ForeignKey(Kategori,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Kategori")
mtarih=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False,verbose_name="Müsabaka Tarihi")

def __str__(self):
    return self.rano
```

how should I try a method

```
class takimlar(models.Model):
kno=models.ForeignKey(Club,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
takim=models.CharField(max_length=50)
created_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.takim)
```

Comment: `return str(self.rano)`. For the second you can however use `return self.takim`, because that is a `str`ing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is quite self-explaining. In your first model, you write:

> ```
> def __str__(self):
>     return self.rano
> ```

But `rano` is a `takimlar` object, since you defined a `ForeignKey` to the `takimlar` model. You can take the *textual representation* of that object, by wrapping it in the `str` constructor:

```
class Musabaka(models.Model):

    # ...

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.rano)
```

As for the `takimlar` model, you do *not* need to call `str(..)` on that, since the `takim` is a `CharField`, hense `self.takim` is already a string, so:

```
class takimlar(models.Model):

    # ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.takim
```